# No grid lines in row header using grid.table() from gridExtra

Tags: r, gridextra

When I shade the row headers in my theme for grid.table, the horizontal lines between the rows don't appear. Sometimes one line will show, but it's thinner than the ones between the core cells.

If I set the row padding to 5 lines, the gridlines sometimes appear, but that obviously isn't practical.

Here's an example:

```
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
t = ttheme_default(
    rowhead=list(
        fg_params=list(fontface="plain"),
        bg_params=list(fill=c(NA, rep("grey80",5)))
    )
)
grid.newpage()
grid.table(iris[1:5, 1:3], theme=t)
```

[image: Example output]

The answer below from baptiste solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have same problem when you click on the Zoom button? I don't!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by default the colour (border) of the background rectangles is set to NA, which in grid takes no space. If you want to see borders, you should set an actual colour, e.g.

```
bg_params=list(fill=c(NA, rep("grey80",5)), col="white")
```

and for thicker lines, use the lwd parameter.